# showing an integral diverges

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on the following problem:

[image: problem]

Edit: So after thinking a little bit more about the problem, here is my (hopefully correct) solution. If there is an error, I would appreciate if someone could point it out.

Suppose that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \,dx $ exists. From the boundedness of $f$, we have $\rho\int_a^b g(x) \,dx \leq \int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,dx $.
By Cauchy's Criterion, $\exists r \in (a,b)$ such that $x_1,x_2 \in (r,b) \implies |\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)g(x) \,dx| < \epsilon$.

Now assume $g > 0$ (otherwise consider $-g$). Then $ \rho M \leq\rho\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g(x) \,dx \leq\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)g(x) \,dx =|\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)g(x) \,dx|   < \epsilon$

Or more simply, $\rho M \leq \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)g(x) \,dx < \epsilon$. However epsilon is arbitrary, $\implies$ $\rho M \leq 0$, a contradiction. Thus $\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \,dx$ diverges.

Comment: Note that the inclusion of border points in integration boundaries is optional, i.e.
$$\int_{[a,b]} = \int_{(a,b)}$$

Comment: I have made an attempt at a solution, any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Maybe go a little easy on the editing. In the past couple of hours, you've bumped almost three dozen years-old questions to the top of the queue. There's already so much current traffic on Math.SE that it's best to limit the influx of old stuff. (See, for instance, [this recent meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29414/409) in the wake of rampant re-tagging of sangaku questions.)

Comment: @Blue heh, thanks for the warning. It's an automated script; I kept an eye on the front page but didn't notice any relevant activity there. Somehow the caching is off, I guess.

Comment: It's good that the process is automated; fixing all those image links by hand would be tedious. :)  Even so, there are over a dozen of your recent edits on the Top Questions/Interesting queue; your eye may not be noticing them, but mine certainly is. :) I see in your Revisions list that another couple-dozen edits were made 12 hours ago. Before then, maybe a dozen or so, then I got bored of counting. You might want to tweak your script to max-out at, say, five edits at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of an integral will also work here. Note that you can choose an infinite sequence of pairs $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2) \ldots$ such that $a < a_1 < b_1 < a_2 < b_2 \ldots$ and all pairs are less than $b$, such that $|\int_{a_j}^{b_j} g(x) dx| \geq M$.  Then in the limit as $j \to \infty$, you will eventually have $|\int_{a_j}^{b_j} f(x)g(x) dx| > M \rho / 2$ since $f$ is continuous. Since $M \rho / 2$ is a fixed constant, this is enough to show the integral diverges.